# AWS EC2 and rvm ssh

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, rvm

I have created user for my AWS ec2 VPS (deployer)

When i am logging with:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws/*...*.pem ubuntu@ec2*...*.amazonaws.com
```

command rvm use 2.0.0 is working correctly

=>

```
    ubuntu@ip-***:~$ rvm list

    rvm rubies

    =* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

    # => - current
    # =* - current && default
    #  * - default

    ubuntu@ip-***:~$ rvm which
    ubuntu@ip-***:~$
```

But when i use **su - deployer** i have got:

```
deployer@ip***:/home/ubuntu$ rvm
    The program 'rvm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
    sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

I would like to understand how correctly write command for ssh login.
I have tried:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws/*.pem *ubuntu@ec2***.amazonaws.com -t 'bash --login -c "rvm"'
```

but received "Connection to ec2-***.amazonaws.com closed".

Within my local machine rvm functioning correctly. I have added

```
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

into my ~/.bash_profile

I have spent 3-5 hours studying stackoverflow topics related to this issue, but still not understand what am i doing wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you install rvm as the user `ubuntu` or only as `deployer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem before and there are 2 ways to solve it.

The first way is to log in directly as the *deployer* user to the instance. This might mean having to create a ssh keypair (see ssh-keygen -t rsa). Then you can log in with `ssh deployer@ec2.instance.address` This way the rvm will be loaded directly to the deployed user's shell.

A second way is not to use the dash when su to the deployed user account.

When you use the dash then you load your own bashrc vs that particular user's bashrc.

So `sudo su deployer`

Comment: Thank you, I managed to log in with ssh directly as deployer using password. But the problem is still unsolved. Rvm within deployer (su - deployer, sudo su deployer) does not work. I have tried a lot of things - add it to remote .bashrc file, send the comand rvm with: ssh deployer@...com bash --login -c "rvm". I cannot understand why it does work with ubuntu user and does not with deployer user. Probably there is some issues in AWS security policy? I think I will use it under ubuntu user and give up attempts to apply this for deployer user.

Answer (score 0):

you nee to use:

```
su - deployer
```

it will ensure you use login shell

Comment: I am sorry, it was misprint, actually there are su - deployer